# Sorting a given matrix in C++ in row major order

Tags: c++, arrays

```
void sortAllWay(int arr[][N]) 
{ 
    // Consider matrix elements (in row major 
    // order) and sort the sequence. 
    int *ptr = (int*) arr; 
    sort(ptr, ptr + N * N); 
}
```

What exactly does this piece of code do?

We passed an array to it, and it has been sorted. I have sorted arrays like `sort(arr, arr + n)` where `n` is the size of the array. However this doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: what is `N` here? Is it a gloabl `#define` or a `const int`?

Answer (score 1):

That's just a function that calls real `std::sort` function for your array.
In case of arrays `std::sort` function gets pointer to the first element of an array and pointer to the end of an array (right after the last element).

Since statically allocated 2-dimensional array stores in memory as single sequence you can iterate over it by incrementing pointer `ptr` till it reaches `ptr+N*N` in your case.

`int *ptr = (int *)arr;` -  pointer to the first element

`ptr+N*N` - pointer to the end of an array (right after the last element)

Comment: Nitpick: `ptr+N*N` is the "one past the end" pointer which is valid but not dereferencable

Comment: @Caleth Yeah, I meant it. 
Thanks, I've added note on it.

Comment: @Bob__ you are right, `std::begin` and `std::end` cannot be used for 2-dimensional arrays, I've just checked. But it kind of wierd, statically allocated array stores in memory as single sequence and we can calculate both beginning and the end.

Comment: @Bob__ also `std::begin` and `std::end` doesn't work with array that passed to a function like that `void printArr(int m[][N])`, that is really strange to me.
https://wandbox.org/permlink/AxSQKeIF5m1gNlJM

Comment: You need a reference to the correct type (meaning an array with the same dimensions): https://wandbox.org/permlink/kjyUVQhkxjFWdFSd or https://wandbox.org/permlink/q1ftmLb7gDV6USTn

Answer (score 0):

`sort(arr, arr + n)` is algorithm in the STL which sorts the elements in the array

A simple demo for sort algorithm

```
   int arr[] = {1, 5, 8, 9, 6, 7, 3, 4, 2, 0}; 

   int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); 

   sort(arr, arr+n); 
   cout << "\nArray after sorting using default sort is : \n"; 

   for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
       cout << arr[i] << " ";
```

**Output :**

> Array after sorting using default sort is :
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

So by default,

> sort() sorts an array in ascending order.

Click this link and study it .

[Sort algorithm STL](https://www-geeksforgeeks-org.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-c-stl/amp/?amp_js_v=a2&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQECAFYAQ%3D%3D#referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geeksforgeeks.org%2Fsort-c-stl%2F)